# difference memory usage on same Object array in two filling way

Tags: java, arrays, memory, jdbc

i want to have an Object Cache by an Array Object
i write a test code to seeing how it taken memory for 3 million class type objects
and it's about ~200MB of Ram and it's very good to have (code is PersonArray1)
but in my real project my data is in DB (Mysql) and must be fetch them into array , so i write a code and test it but memory usage make me confused!
because i could to read data without putting in Array and Ram usage is about 23MB but when i put them in Array it's taken very huge memory 300MB for just 100,000 indexes!!(code is PersonArray2)
 in real i must be have 3 million indexes
in now i have 1 million rows in my Table and i think for all them i need about 3GB of Ram and compare to first way it's not good
at first i think it's taken by "ResultSet" or "Statement" Objects but it's not !

because just when i putting them in Array memory eaten for seeing that uncomment line of 45 and comment line of 43
anyway i think i have a mistake in my code because two array of same thing is not different logically but why this is happen and how to correct it ?

```
    package test;

    public class Person {

            int province;
            int city;
            int area;
            long phone;
            int userType;
            int situation;
            int score;
            int uid;
            int priority;
            long date;
            String content;

        public Person(int province, int city, int area, long phone, int userType, int situation, int score, int uid, int priority, long date, String content) {
            this.province = province;
            this.city = city;
            this.area = area;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.userType = userType;
            this.situation = situation;
            this.score = score;
            this.uid = uid;
            this.priority = priority;
            this.date = date;
            this.content = content;
        }

    }
```

```
package test;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PersonArray1 {

    static Random r = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Person[] arr = new Person[3000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = new Person(r.nextInt(1000), r.nextInt(1000), r.nextInt(1000), r.nextLong(),
                    r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(5), r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(10000), r.nextLong(),
                    "Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, "
                    + "and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. "
                    + "It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for "
                    + "mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation,"
                    + " eg typography, font, or layout. Lorem ipsum is mostly a part of a Latin text by"
                    + " the classical author and philosopher Cicero. Its words and letters have been "
                    + "changed by addition or removal, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical;"
                    + " it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's "
                    + "still resembles classical Latin, it actually has no meaning whatsoever. As Cicero's"
                    + " text doesn't contain the letters K, W, or Z, alien to latin, these, and others are"
                    + " often inserted randomly to mimic the typographic appearence of European languages, "
                    + "as are digraphs not to be found in the original.");
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
        // using Scanner for dont aloowing to finish process and seeing Ram usage by task manager
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.next();
    }
}
```

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import services.persistence2.DBServicesAutoCommit;

public class CreateTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // "DBServicesAutoCommit" is a static Connection Pool
        Connection con = DBServicesAutoCommit.getConnection();
        try {
            Statement ps = con.createStatement();
            ps.execute("CREATE TABLE `person`(\n"
                    + "`province` INT NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "`city` INT,\n"
                    + "`area` INT,\n"
                    + "`phone` bigint,\n"
                    + "`usertype` INT NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "`situation` TINYINT NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "`score` INT,\n"
                    + "`uid` INT NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "`priority` INT NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "`date` BIGINT NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "`content` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL\n"
                    + ") ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;");
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import services.persistence2.DBServicesManualCommit;

public class FillPersonDB {

    static Random r = new Random();
    private static String createPersons = "insert into person(province,city,area,phone,usertype,situation,score,uid,priority,date,content)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    public static void createPersons() {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            // "DBServicesManualCommit" is a static Connection Pool without auto commit
            con = DBServicesManualCommit.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(createPersons);
            // it's take long time but you could to set for 50,000 and fill DB by 20 concurrent connections (multi thread) for just 5 minutes
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                ps.setInt(1, r.nextInt(1000));
                ps.setInt(2, r.nextInt(1000));
                ps.setInt(3, r.nextInt(1000));
                ps.setLong(4, r.nextLong());
                ps.setInt(5, r.nextInt(100));
                ps.setInt(6, r.nextInt(5));
                ps.setInt(7, r.nextInt(100));
                ps.setInt(8, r.nextInt(100));
                ps.setInt(9, r.nextInt(10000));
                ps.setLong(10, r.nextLong());
                ps.setString(11, "Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, "
                        + "and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. "
                        + "It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for "
                        + "mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation,"
                        + " eg typography, font, or layout. Lorem ipsum is mostly a part of a Latin text by"
                        + " the classical author and philosopher Cicero. Its words and letters have been "
                        + "changed by addition or removal, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical;"
                        + " it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's "
                        + "still resembles classical Latin, it actually has no meaning whatsoever. As Cicero's"
                        + " text doesn't contain the letters K, W, or Z, alien to latin, these, and others are"
                        + " often inserted randomly to mimic the typographic appearence of European languages, "
                        + "as are digraphs not to be found in the original.");
                ps.addBatch();
                if (i % 10000 == 0) {
                    ps.executeBatch();
                    con.commit();
                }
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
            con.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FillPersonDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FillPersonDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FillPersonDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import services.persistence2.DBServicesManualCommit;

public class PersonArray2 {

    private static String getPersons = "select * from person limit 100000";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonArray2 pa = new PersonArray2();
        Person[] person = pa.getPersons();
        pa = null;
        System.gc();
        // using Scanner for dont aloowing to finish process and seeing Ram usage by task manager
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.next();
    }

    public Person[] getPersons() {
        Statement s = null;
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Person[] person = new Person[1000000];

        try {

            int c = 0;
            long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
            con = DBServicesManualCommit.getConnection();
            s = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            s.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            rs = s.executeQuery(getPersons);
            System.out.println("before while");
            while (rs.next()) {
                // when i dont asign new Person Object to Array ram usage is very low but just asigning Object to array eaten memory a lot
                person[c] = new Person(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getLong(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6), rs.getInt(7), rs.getInt(8), rs.getInt(9), rs.getLong(10), rs.getString(11));
                // normal memory usage without putting into array
                //new Person(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getLong(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6), rs.getInt(7), rs.getInt(8), rs.getInt(9), rs.getLong(10), rs.getString(11));
                if (c++ % 10000 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Current Index is :"+(c-1));
                }
            }
           System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - l);
           System.out.println(person.length + "|" + person[99999].phone);
            return person;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PersonArray2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    rs = null;
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PersonArray2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (s != null) {
                try {
                    s.close();
                    s = null;
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PersonArray2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                    con = null;
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PersonArray2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please point us to the array that you are filling and describing which types and kinds of objects are put into it?

Comment: @JFMeier it's Person type in both mode , you could to see in the code

Comment: @java acm You allocate room for 1,000,000 Person, not 100,000: `Person[] person = new Person[1000000];`.  Using constants instead of hard coded numbers will help avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: On thing you might consider is the use of Strings. In your first example all of your Person objects contain the same String. In Java identical String literals are references to the same String in memory.

Comment: A database is precisely used to be able to quickly query for information in a very large set without having this set in memory. Why do you load all this in memory? Just query the database, that's what it's for. That said, in your first test, all your person instances reference the same, unique String object, which exists only once in memory. In the second one, all person instances reference their own String object. So they're completely different. Your first test is just completely unrealistic.

Comment: @JBNizet when you used   Statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE); , it's resolved memory heap exception and not a problem , and when you called rs.getInt(1) it's returned int value not Integer

Comment: @java acm Why are you calling `s.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`?  Are you using the MySQL JDBC driver?

Comment: Each object uses a minimum of 64 bytes plus the size of the String will be at least 32 bytes.  When you create objects without retaining them, they get garbage collected. This is why each object appears to be 23/3 = < 8 bytes each when you don't keep them.

Comment: @Tibrogargan it's a technic for fetching a lot of rows when you want to use normal memory usage , in this case my table size is about 3.1GB and yes we dont want to eat memory for just a select operation

Comment: @java acm I know.  But it is specific to MySQL.  If you're using something else it may not have the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes it's MySql 5.7 i want to edit my previous comment but my time was up

Comment: @JBNizet OMG !! all equal Strings have same memory allocation and it's reason of test 1 is taken very low memory i just add "i" variable to String and then seeing Memory condition ! , you said right , and reasons to have Cache Object is i have very huge read (also fields query) on this Object and DB could not to handle that throughput . at first of this project we dont have more budget to bought more server for Elasticsearch or DB nodes , do you have any cheap solution for this bottleneck ?